# Can I pull the emails off my Android phone?

Tags: email, restore

I recently lost all the emails on my laptop computer. And they were important business emails. Many of those emails still exist on my Android phone. I know I can forward them all, but that will take a lot of time and then they'll all be in my inbox from me, not the original sender.

Is there any way to pull the emails off and then drop them in to my mail program?

Comment: Unlikely. Of course it depends on the mail app you're using, but I've never read any of them has the feature to export all your mails in any way to use it directly on your PC (e.g. as `.mbox` files). On your device, they are most likely stored inside a SQLite database.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no easy way to do this. Here is the method I found...

Open an email on your phone and find where you can "save email as file". It is usually in the upper right dropdown. After saving, go to your phone's storage and find the Saved Email folder. The email will be saved as an *.eml file. Since the file is relatively small, you can do this for multiple emails. (It is a little time consuming to open emails and save as files but once you get the hang of it you can go pretty fast.) All you are doing is opening emails and saving them to that Saved Email folder.

Next, using an email account, email the *.eml file(s) to the email address you want to place the emails in. Remember you can attach multiple files in one email since they are small files. Now open the email account on your computer with the attachments and select an *.eml file. When you open the attachment it will appear as an open email. Move the open email to the folder you want it to appear in.

The email will now be in that folder and appear just as it was on your phone. Unfortunately you now have to spend time opening each *.eml file as an email and moving it to the desired folder. At least now the emails will be saved where you want them in the order (date and time) as they appeared on your phone.

Answer (score 0):

You can try out any of the Backup App, that would let you have fun!

The thing that you're saying

> I recently lost all the emails on my laptop computer. And they were important business emails. Many of those emails still exist on my Android phone.

As the mails on your device might get removed as soon as you connect it to the Internet (sync might do that), if you need to install a backup app better download its `.apk` file to your computer, and sideload it (e.g. copy it to your SDCard, and start the `.apk` using any file manager, which would trigger the installation; make sure to have [unknown-sources](/questions/tagged/unknown-sources) activated for this). A good choice would be [Helium Backup](http://www.appbrain.com/app/helium-app-sync-and-backup/com.koushikdutta.backup): it creates `.ab` (Android Backup) files compatible with `adb backup`, and there are solutions available to extract those on your PC.

> Is there any way to pull the emails off and then drop them in to my mail program?

No, there is no direct way to do that – you could only forward them, which you don't want. Then I don't think there is any other way to do this. You can either create a backup file to just save the emails, then forward them. That's the only way to get back your emails, but still you will lose the time, sender name and other! And it will be replaced with Sender as: You, Time: Current Time, Body: Body will have the email included as signature or something like that. That's it!

Good luck, Cheers.

Comment: The `.apk` file is just the app installer, so that won't contain the mails at all.

Comment: No no what I mean, was to get the `apk` file of the backup! Because when he will try to connect to wifi or any other service. Email app will try to sync and he will loose the email, so I suggested to download the apk file of the Backup app! I never meant the apk of email service! Sorry for confusion

Comment: `.apk` files are always only app installer, never data – so there is no such thing as an *`apk` file of the backup*. If the mail app itself offers to backup mails (or another app such as *Helium* is used), those backups are for sure not in `apk` format. If you don't believe me, see e.g. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APK_%28file_format%29) :)

Comment: -_- @Izzy Izzy Izzy, Pardom me for this confusion! What I mean is, to download the `apk` file of the app that would do the backup things, like the one that backs up the messages. Then after installing that app, he should back up his emails to the sd card using that app. I never meant the apk creation of the backup file or whatso ever, and I do believe you! Apk is like executable (.exe) file on Windows. It has nothing to do with the data backup!

Comment: Ahh! Now you make sense :) That should go inside your answer, so others don't get as confused as me :) I will do that for you, please check my edit afterwards if I got things right.

Comment: Yah sure! :) You can edit it..

Comment: Done already (in case you want to check).

Comment: Yes, can you remove downvote now?

Comment: No. It's not mine. I don't downvote when I might have misunderstood something. Only when I'm sure a post deserves it. This did not :)

Comment: Ohh..well I guess its the asker! He might not want this answer hehehe..